# Calling pentaho report from another pentaho report

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I need to a call a pentaho report header of PRPT from another PRPT(without using subreport).

Exact requirement:

Report header part will change dynamically(Label position , number of labels , Number of text and all the alignments). So will give one prpt to the user to design it depends on their request. Once they done with their design part they will save that prpt. That saved prpt should call in report header of the main report on the go. Kindly guide us how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible without coding. If you have your own reporting engine embedded in your application you can achieve that, generating your own prpt definition and using it then in some point.

In the other hand, if you don't wanna code, you can change all those things dinamically using the expression properties, and apply the format required based on the request parameters.

1. Specify the parameters you need in the report to calculate the header.
2. Select the item you need to be dinamically customizable
3. In the value attribute choose the plus sign (+) and specifiy the formula you need to get the desired format, eg: in the color value you can specify something like

> =IF([PROVIDER]="STACKOVERFLOW";"orange";"")

You must define all the attributes you need like visible, positions, alignments, a long and hard but nice job.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chocho. I have implemented the report the same way you have recommended.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark as correct answer, if it solved your question.